# I am getting an error "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'size' in base 'Nil'"

Tags: gdscript, godot4

I am new to Godot. Trying to make a counter for some values of reactor core. Here is my code

```
extends Control
var player_words = []
var current_story = {}



@onready var PlayerText = $VBoxContainer/HBoxContainer/LineEdit
@onready var Displaytext= $VBoxContainer/Label
@onready var Butlabel=$VBoxContainer/HBoxContainer/Label2
func _ready():
    pick_current_story()

    Displaytext.text="Bienvenidoooo "
    check_player_words_lenght()
    PlayerText.grab_focus()
func pick_current_story():
    var stories = get_from_json("StoryBook.json")
    randomize()
    current_story = stories[randi() % stories.size()]
    #var storyBook = $StoryBook  # Supongo que hay un nodo Node2D llamado 'StoryBook' en tu escena
    #var stories = storyBook.get_child_count()
    #var selected_story = randi() % stories
    #current_story = {
        #"prompts": storyBook.get_child(selected_story).prompts,
    #   "story": storyBook.get_child(selected_story).story
    #}

func get_from_json(filename):
    var file : FileAccess = FileAccess.open("res://" + filename, FileAccess.READ) # Opens file
    var content = JSON.parse_string(file.get_as_text())
    file.flush() # Good practice to close the file when we are done with it
    return content # Return the JSON content
    
func _on_line_edit_text_submitted(new_text):
    add_to_player_words()
func _on_texture_button_pressed():
    if is_story_done():
        get_tree().reload_current_scene()
    else:
        add_to_player_words()
func add_to_player_words():
    player_words.append(PlayerText.text)
    Displaytext.text=""
    PlayerText.clear()
    check_player_words_lenght()
func is_story_done():
    return player_words.size()==current_story.prompts.size()
func check_player_words_lenght():
    if is_story_done():
        end_game()
    else:
        prompt_player()

func tell_story():
    Displaytext.text=current_story.story % player_words
    
func prompt_player():
    Displaytext.text+= "May I Have"+ current_story.prompts[player_words.size()] + " please"
func end_game():
    PlayerText.queue_free() 
    Butlabel.text="Again"
    tell_story()
```

I want to use JSon, but the course that i take perhaps is un GODOT 3 and i use Godot 4. I need solve the problem the most quickly possibly

I am expecting fix my problem that i can't resolve for many methods
That is the image about the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you are trying to access `size` on something invalid.

But you didn't tell us which line got the error. *I shouldn't be answering this, but I'll play where was the error?*

---

The error could be in any of these places:

- `current_story = stories[randi() % stories.size()]`
- `return player_words.size()==current_story.prompts.size()`
- `Displaytext.text+= "May I Have"+ current_story.prompts[player_words.size()] + " please"`

Which means that the list of things that are possible invalid is:

- `stories` (from the first line mentioned above)
- `player_words` (from the second and third lines mentioned above)
- `current_story.prompts` (from the second line mentioned above)

Where do you set them? And can that fail?

- `stories` is set here:

  ```
  var stories = get_from_json("StoryBook.json")
  ```

  So we have to see `get_from_json`:

  ```
  func get_from_json(filename):
      var file : FileAccess = FileAccess.open("res://" + filename, FileAccess.READ) # Opens file
      var content = JSON.parse_string(file.get_as_text())
      file.flush() # Good practice to close the file when we are done with it
      return content # Return the JSON content
  ```

  We see that is has no branches, and it always returns `content`, which is set from [`JSON.parse_string`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_json.html#class-json-method-parse-string). From the documentation we find that `parse_string`:

  > Attempts to parse the `json_string` provided and returns the parsed data. Returns `null` if parse failed.

  So if the contents read are not a valid JSON, you `get_from_json` returns `null`. And, of course, `null` does not have a `size`.

  It is worth noting that if it didn't find the file you are trying to read, you would have a different error.
- `player_words` is set here:

  ```
  var player_words = []
  ```

  I don't see it being set anywhere else, so - unless another script is messing with it - it should remain an `Array`, and thus getting its `size` is OK.
- `current_story.prompts` is isn't set directly, instead `current_story` is set in a few places:

  - ```
    var current_story = {}
    ```

    Initialized as a `Dictionary`, without any items. So if you were to try to access `current_story.prompts` without setting `current_story` again, it would fail.
  - ```
    current_story = stories[randi() % stories.size()]
    ```

  As we saw earlier, `stories` is set from JSON. So if the JSON does not have any `prompts` then `current_story` won't either, which will also result in failure.

As you can see, I cannot fully discard any of these. At least I can say that `player_words` being the problem is unlikely because why would you mess with it from another script?

We also observe that before we can have a valid `current_story` we need a valid `stories`. So I'll tackle them in that order...

- To guarantee that `player_words` remains valid, you can specify the type of its variable:

  Either implicly:

  ```
  var player_words := []
  ```

  Or explicitly:

  ```
  var player_words:Array = []
  ```

  *And you could do the same for `current_story` while you are at it.
- About `stories`... You are going to run into another problem: is your json file imported at all?

  Reading the `.json` file will work on desktop when launching from the editor, because in that case `res://` is mapped to the real project folder. But once exported, the imported resources are packaged (by default in a `.pck` file) and the `res://` references to files in that package... So you would need to make sure the `.json` file is imported as a resource. But if it were imported as a resource you would `load` it, would you not?

  *That is not the problem at hand, I'm just giving you a heads up.*

  I know that in your tests you are being able to open the `.json`, otherwise that would have been the error, so let us move on from that...

  The other ways this can go wrong is that the file is not valid JSON, or that it is valid JSON but does not contain `prompts`. I cannot tell because I'm not looking at the JSON file.

  On good faith, I'll assume the JSON file is valid and correct.
- And we get to `current_story.prompts`... If the JSON file is valid and correct, you must be trying to access `current_story.prompts` before `current_story` has been set with an entry from the JSON, are you?

  For that to happen `is_story_done` must be running before `pick_current_story`. Which as far as I can tell cannot happen from this script, even assuming the methods `_on_line_edit_text_submitted` and `_on_texture_button_pressed` are connected to matching signals. So, it seems this would only fail if there is another script calling methods out of order.

---

Thus, I must conclude that the most likely cause is that your JSON is incorrect. With a second likely cause being another script interfering with the shown one.

I understand that JSON has some advantages (being easy to edit with external tools, and not being too bad for version control), however I would like to suggest a custom `Resource` class. It could be fully typed, and you would have guaranteed that Godot will import it, which will save some headache.

It could be like this:

```
class_name Story
extends Resource

@export var prompts:Array[String]
@export var text:String
```

And you can export an array of them:

```
@export var stories:Array[Story]
```